# Al intentar seleccionar valores de botones, al hacer clic al primer botón se obtiene de manera normal el id del mismo, no así con el segundo y tercero

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de obtener el valor *idmesa* al hacer clic en un botón. Estos valores se obtienen de una base de datos.

```js
$("#mesa").on("click",function(event){
   
    event.preventDefault();
    
  let element = $(this)[0];
  let id = $(element).attr('idmesa');
alert(id);


  });
```

```css
.contenedormesas {

    border: 1px dashed red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display:  flex;
  
  
}
.contmesas{
    
    width: 100%;
    border:1px black dashed;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
    height: inherit;
    padding-top: 20px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.mesa{

    height: 150px;


    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedormesas">
   <div class="mesa"><button class="mesaboton" id="mesa" idmesa='1'>Mesa 1</button></div>

   <div class="mesa"><button class="mesaboton"  id="mesa" idmesa='2'>Mesa 2</button></div>

   <div class="mesa"><button class="mesaboton"  id="mesa" idmesa='3'>Mesa 3</button></div>
   </div>
```

Cuando se le da clic al primer botón se obtiene de manera normal el id del botón, pero cuando le doy clic al segundo y al tercero no pasa nada. ¿A qué se debe este problema?

Comment: [Los id deben ser únicos en el DOM...](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza este script que funciona en tu código:

```
$(".mesaboton").on("click",function(event){
    let element = $(this)[0];
    let id = $(element).attr('idmesa');
    alert(id);

});
```

Te explico: los id's son únicos y no se deben repetir, se deben usar en su caso las clases, en este caso *mesaboton*.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alex tu codigo resolvio el problema

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo HTML has puesto las id iguales. Las id deben ser únicas. Lo he realizado con la clase, esta si puede estar repetida. El único cambio que he hecho ha sido en la llamada a la clase desde jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .contenedormesas {

border: 1px dashed red;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

display:  flex;


}
.contmesas{

width: 100%;
border:1px black dashed;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
height: inherit;
padding-top: 20px;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.mesa{

height: 150px;



}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedormesas">
        <div class="mesa"><button class="mesaboton" id="mesa" idmesa='1'>Mesa 1</button></div>

        <div class="mesa"><button class="mesaboton"  id="mesa" idmesa='2'>Mesa 2</button></div>
        
        <div class="mesa"><button class="mesaboton"  id="mesa" idmesa='3'>Mesa 3</button></div>
   </div>

   
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(".mesaboton").on("click",function(event){
   
   event.preventDefault();
   
 let element = $(this)[0];
 let id = $(element).attr('idmesa');
alert(id);


 });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias jbort

Answer (score 0):

con `$("#mesa")` haces referencia solo a **un elemento**, y recordar que el atributo id solo es permitido **a un elemento** por eso solo toma al primero. Si quieres hacer la escucha a los demás botones deberías hacerlo con alguna otra propiedad que tengan en común (por ejemplo una clase), y como esto te devolverá un array, debería iterar y hacer el listener para todos esos elementos.

```
    $(".mesaboton").each((index, item)=>{
        console.log($(item).on('click', ()=>{
            const idMesa = $(item).attr('idmesa')
            alert(idMesa)
        }))      
    })
```